# EZaudio execute in Background

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, background, ezaudio

I tried.

```
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier task=0;
task=[application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    NSLog(@"Expiration handler called %f",[application backgroundTimeRemaining]);
    [application endBackgroundTask:task];
    task=UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];
```

I want to display waveform when I record the audio.I have use the `EZAudio` class but it will crash when I press HOME button or Lock Screen.
How can I run the app in background please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just i have used `EZAudioPlot` change to `EZAudioPlotGL`.
select `EZAudioPlotGL` view change only class name of view goto identity inspector and change it `EZAudioPlot`. after that

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet EZAudioPlotGL *audioPlot;
```

Change it

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet EZAudioPlot *audioPlot;
```

its work fine.